# Why do we wrap a SSL public key with a certificate?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

With some research I know

- how the public/private keys work
- SSL certificate wraps the public key
- given a Certificate Signing Requests (CSR), Certificate Authorities (CA) issues certificates
- when an user first connects to an SSL-secured website, the user first verifies the certificate with a trusted third party

I read that SSL certificates promise users that they are connecting to the party which they think they are connecting to. **What does this mean? What extra security does wrapping the public key provide us, as opposed to just having the public key itself?** An example would be greatly appreciated.

E.g. If Facebook only gives me its public key, instead of an SSL certificate wrapping the public key, what dangers would I be exposed to? Is making sure the address bar reading https://www.facebook.com/ not enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is making sure the address bar reading https://www.facebook.com/ not enough?

A public key doesn't have a name, so you'd connect to a host, and it would give you a key, and that would be it.  If an attacker was able to intercept your request they'd just give you their own public key and you'd not have any way of knowing he wasn't facebook.com

> what dangers would I be exposed to?

Man-in-the-middle is the main threat.  The defenses against it are all in the certificate:

- The certificate SubjectAltNames extension or Subject value say what the intended property is for a certificate.
- The certificate says who issued it.  So you can say "yeah? sez who?", and it says "Well, says VeriSign".

  - Then you can look to see if VeriSign is someone that you're comfortable with making the trust decision for you (that is, is VeriSign in your root trust list)
- A CA can keep track of when a client has reported their key as stolen, so the CA can mark the certificate as revoked.

  - This means that even though it says it's good for facebook.com, the CA says it's good for nothing, and probably you're talking to the person who stole it, not with facebook.com.

Answer (score 1):

By wrapping the public key in a certificate you can verify that:

- The key really belongs to the party you want to access. The certificate provides this by having the domain in the subject. And you know you can trust this information because the certificate is directly or indirectly signed by a locally trusted certificate agency.
- The key is still valid and not compromised. The certificate has a lifetime (begin and end) and can also be revoked.
- The key can be used for server authentication. The issuing CA puts the appropriate key usage information into the certificate.